# computed field inside field collection

Tags: 7

I have two fields (*field_a* and *field_b*) which are inside the *field_available_water_s* field collection. I want to set the *field_c* computed field, which is also inside the field collection, to the sum of those fields.

I tried using this code, but it doesn't work.

```php
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_a[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] + $entity->field_b[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

What code should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Computed Code (PHP)* textarea shown in the field settings of the computed field, you need to enter the following code.

```php
$field_a = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, "field_a");
$field_b = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, "field_b");
$entity_field[0]["value"] = $field_a[0]["value"] + $field_b[0]["value"];
```

That is the code the description for the *Computed Code (PHP)* textarea uses as example. (Emphasis is mine.)

> The variables available to your code include: `&$entity_field`,
> `$entity_type`, `$entity`, `$field`, `$instance`, `$langcode`, and
> `$items`. To set the value of the field, set
> `$entity_field[0]['value']`. For multi-value computed fields continue
> with `$entity_field[1]['value']`. Here's **a simple example which sets
> the computed field's value to the value of the sum of the number
> fields (field_a and field_b)** in a node entity:
>
> ```php
> $field_a = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, "field_a");
> $field_b = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, "field_b");
> $entity_field[0]["value"] = $field_a[0]["value"] + $field_b[0]["value"];
> ```

> [image: screenshot]

I added the fields described in the question to a node. With this code, I get the following output.

> [image: screenshot]